# loading tablelayoutpanel need handle on respective error provider

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `TableLayoutPanel` and I'm iterating over a collection to dynamically build the contents of the table. I'm trying to include an `ErrorProvider` for each `ComboBox` that is generated. However, I don't know how to get the handle of the respective error provider in the combo box validated event handler?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    TableLayoutPanel _tableLayoutPanel1;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _tableLayoutPanel1 = new TableLayoutPanel();
        _tableLayoutPanel1.AutoSize = true;

        BuildTableContents();

        this.Controls.Add(_tableLayoutPanel1);
    }

    private void BuildTableContents()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Label labelLeft = new Label();
            labelLeft.Text = "Test Left Column";
            _tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(labelLeft, 0, i);

            ComboBox cbo = new ComboBox();
            cbo.Validated += new EventHandler(cbo_Validated);
            cbo.Name = "cbo_" + i;
            cbo.Items.AddRange(new object[] { "Yes", "No" });
            _tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(cbo, 1, i);

            ErrorProvider err = new ErrorProvider();
            err.SetIconAlignment(cbo, ErrorIconAlignment.MiddleRight);
        }
    }

    void cbo_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //How do I get a handle on associated 
        //Error Provider to current combo box?

    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ValidateChildren();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try placing the ErrorProvider at the form scope level:

```
TableLayoutPanel _tableLayoutPanel1;
ErrorProvider err = new ErrorProvider();

public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: BTW, Eventhough I'm getting errors now the ValidateChildren() is always returning True?

Comment: @Rod I think you have to make sure you call e.Cancel = true in your control's validation code.